# C++ vector data strucure, loop only half of elements

Tags: c++

how to loop only half of the elements in C++ vector data structure using `auto` keyword

```
vector<string> InputFIle;

    void iterateHalf(){
        /* iterate only from begin to half of the size */
        for (auto w = InputFIle.begin(); w != InputFIle.end(); w++) {
            cout << *w << " : found " << endl;
        }
      }
```

Comment: What type is `InputFIle`? Does it have `size`? Did you try `w != InputFIle.begin()+InputFIle.size()/2`?

Comment: @Quimby a vector of strings

Comment: @Quimby doesn’t really need size. Can do `std::distance` with begin and end.

Comment: `for (auto w = InputFIle.begin(), end = w+InputFIle.size() / 2; w != end; ++w) ...`

Comment: @fabian seems complicated. how about the other half. how can I iterate in other function the second half in the vector

Comment: A `for` loop seems complicated? You'd better get used to them. This kind of control flow happens all the time.

Comment: well it is a little more complicate than range based for, but the question doesn't use one either so.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo solution from fabian  seems to work
can you please show me how can I loop the other half of the vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compute begin and end of your loop, i.e. `first` and `last_exclusive`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::vector<int> vec(16);
    std::iota(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0);

    size_t first = 3;
    size_t last_exclusive = 7;

    //loop using indices
    for(size_t i = first; i < last_exclusive; i++){
        const auto& w = vec[i];
        std::cout << w << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    //loop using iterators
    for(auto iterator = vec.begin() + first; iterator != vec.begin() + last_exclusive;  ++iterator){
        const auto& w = *iterator;
        std::cout << w << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

}
```